# cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am intending to visualise the data using a pairplot after using StandardScaler,
But my code is producing the following  error

```
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Full code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
X = iris.drop(columns='species')
y = iris['species']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

X_train=StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_train)

sns.pairplot(data=pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1), hue=y_train.name)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using `StandardScaler`, your X_train (which was a `pd.DataFrame` before) has become a `numpy.ndarray`, so that's why you cannot concat `X_train` and `y_train`. Because `X_train` is a NumPy array and `y_train` is a Pandas DataFrame

To use concat, both `X_train` and `y_train` has to be a Pandas DataFrame, so convert `X_train` to a DataFrame using this code.

```
X_train = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_train)

X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns = X.columns)
sns.pairplot(data=pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1), hue=y_train.name)
plt.show()
```

It will work.

Comment: it works fine, but it again shows the same error when X_train in a gobal variable and is from another method , any idea why?

Comment: Didn't understand. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: My X_train is generated in a different method(def) and is declared as global , when i try to concantinate after converting it into a dataframe, it shows an error, let me try to reproduce the error and update

Comment: @Ctrl7 I am waiting.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't reproduce the error it's a long program, however this is the code i use to declare X_train as global ```                global scaled_data
            scaled_data=stdcl.fit_transform(X_train)
            scaled_data=pd.DataFrame(scaled_data, columns = X.columns)        ``` and this code in visualization block  ```          data_concat=pd.concat([scaled_data, y_train], axis=1)
         sns.kdeplot(
         data=data_concat)                  
         plt.savefig("kdeplot")   ```

Comment: Sorry, I tried but, I can't help you with this.